# Block every file under git directory

Tags: nginx

I just tried this:

```
location ~ /\.  { return 403; }
```

but if I request /.git/config it's downloaded without any problem.

I really don't understand why

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working regardless how "deep" the requested path goes. Also, a `404` sounds like a better solution, because that way you won't even let someone know that it exists.

```
location ~ /\.(.*)/?(.*)? {
    return 404;
}
```